# Add new field in opencart database

Tags: php, mysql, database, opencart

i make a plugin in opencart that require to add extra field in the database
the field is model_choice int (255) in the product table 
how to make it in product files that when replace files add this field if not exist

Comment: Did you use vqmod for your plugin?

Comment: no , i just change code for product files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below function in your model file to check whether the field exists in Database or not:

```
public function checkFieldModelChoice() {
  $hasModelChoiceField = FALSE;
  $result = $this->db->query( "DESCRIBE `".DB_PREFIX."product`;" );
  foreach ($result->rows as $row) {
     if ($row['Field'] == 'model_choice') {
        $hasModelChoiceField = TRUE;
        break;
     }
  }
  if (!$hasModelChoiceField) {
     $sql = "ALTER TABLE `".DB_PREFIX."product` ADD `model_choice` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''";
     $this->db->query( $sql );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks this code solved my problem well but i put this code without function because i cannot call this function in any action so i put it in admin and catalog (product.tpl).

Comment: That's not a good way. I'm sure that you can use it as function. Check the working of forms in admin catalog and product pages.